# Why the adjective "vague" comes after the noun "change"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

In Longman dictionary there is an example for *disingenuous* which says "Keeping the details of the tax changes vague is disingenuous."
the adjective *vague* precedes the verb *is* and follows the noun *change*

Comment: The adjective _vague_ modifies the earlier noun _details_, but the prepositional phrase "of the tax changes" is also attached to the noun _details_. In that situation (in English), the prepositional phrase commonly precedes the modifying adjective, as in this syntactically similar sentence: "Keeping the dictator of the country happy was essential."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *vague* is applied to "the details of the tax changes". The word *is* then calls "Keeping the details ... vague" disingenuous.

In other words, the example asserts that it is disingenuous to "keep the details ... vague".